# creating a looping counter using RequestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript

I am pretty stuck on what I would have thought was pretty rudimentary.

I want the counter to work between 0 to 2000, and loop between those two time periods.

I have tried resetting each of the variables (as you can see from my console.logs) and nothing seems to work. I am really stumped!

Any help would be most appreciated.

```
'use strict';

window.onload = function() {

  const time = {
    start: performance.now(),
    total: 2000
  };

  const tick = (now) => {
    
    time.elapsed = now - time.start;
    
    if (time.elapsed <= time.total) {
      requestAnimationFrame(tick)
      console.log(now);
    } else {
      console.log('ended')
      console.log(`time elapsed = ${time.elapsed}`)
      time.elapsed = 0;
      time.start = performance.now();
      console.log(`time elapsed = ${time.elapsed}`)
      console.log(`time start = ${time.start}`)
      console.log(`now = ${now}`);
      now = 0;
      //requestAnimationFrame(tick) <-- creates infinite loop
    }

  };

  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}
```

I have also tried a second way, investigating if it related to two RaF inclusions. I also switched the if statement logic around, assuming that elapsed is greater than time.total, and resetting every counter it would work.

This produces exactly the same result.

```
window.onload = function() {

  const time = {
    start: performance.now(),
    total: 2000
  };

  const tick = (now) => {
        
    if (time.elapsed >= time.total) {
      console.log('ended')
      time.elapsed = 0;
      time.now = 0;
      time.start = performance.now();
    }

    time.elapsed = now - time.start;
    requestAnimationFrame(tick)
    console.log(now);

  };
  
  tick();

}
```

Comment: `creates infinite loop` - you want that, don't you? so that after it elapses, it starts all over again - at least, your description of what you want suggests that after 2000 milliseconds the counter is zeroed, and you start again (you don't need  `now = 0` by the way) - if you uncomment that commented line, your code does exactly what you want

Comment: @JaromandaX hi thank you for your comment. I want the counter/timer to run from 0 to 2000, reset to 0, then 0 to 2000, reset.... If I uncomment my RaF line, all that happens is I get a console.log every 2000ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to loop over and over form 0 to 2000 you don't need to check the total elapsed time.

You can have the number of iterations and total elapsed time plus the elapsed time of the current period.

```js
'use strict';

window.onload = function() {

  const time = {
    start: performance.now(),
    periodNO: 0,
    periodDuration: 2000,
    periodElapsedTime: 0,
    totalElapsedTime: 0,
  };

  const tick = (now) => {
    
    time.totalElapsedTime = now - time.start;
    time.periodNO = Math.floor(time.totalElapsedTime / time.periodDuration)
    time.periodElapsedTime = (time.totalElapsedTime - time.periodNO * time.periodDuration);
    
    console.log('Period NO :=> ', time.periodNO);
    console.log('Period Elpased Time :=> ', time.periodElapsedTime);

    let elem = '<div> iteration count :=> ' +  time.periodNO + '</div>';
    elem += '<div> Current period :=> ' + time.periodElapsedTime + '</div>';
    elem += '<div> Total elapsed time :=> ' + time.totalElapsedTime + '</div>';
    document.body.innerHTML = elem;

    requestAnimationFrame(tick);

  };

  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your example; it works! I now need to study it and know how to improve my skillset.

Comment: @dimButTries this link my help you to understand `requestAnimationFrame` better [https://javascript.info/js-animation](https://javascript.info/js-animation)